# How to plot regression line on hexbins with Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've finally managed to wrangle my hexbin distribution plot into something almost pretty.

```
import seaborn as sns

x = req.apply_clicks
y = req.reqs_wordcount

sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="#5d5d60",
         joint_kws={'gridsize':40, 'bins':'log'})
```

[image: Seaborn Hexbin]

But I'm hoping to overlay a regression line on top of it, and can't figure out how to do so. For instance, the regression line seems to occupy the marginal plot when I add regplot to the code:

```
x = req.apply_clicks
y = req.reqs_wordcount
z = sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="#5d5d60",
         joint_kws={'gridsize':40, 'bins':'log'})
sns.regplot(x, y, data=z, color="#5d5d60", scatter=False)
```

[image: regplot in marginal plot]

How to include the regression line in the body of the chart?

Comment: Sure, use `regplot` with `scatter=False`.

Comment: @mwaskom I can't seem to get jointplot and regplot to play nice together. I edited my question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify the axes you want the regression line to be drawn on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the axes you want the `regplot` to appear on. Here is an example, with some made-up data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = 0.3 + 0.3 * np.random.randn(10000)
y = 0.1 - 0.2 * x + 0.1 * np.random.randn(10000)
mask = (y > 0) & (x > 0)
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]

g = sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="#5d5d60",
                  joint_kws={'gridsize':40, 'bins':'log'})
sns.regplot(x, y, ax=g.ax_joint, scatter=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful. Now if only I could change the style of the marginal plots to match the main chart (or remove them altogether).

Comment: Regarding figure style, [this part of Seaborn's documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/aesthetics.html) might be helpful. You might try ``sns.set_style("white")``

Comment: Where did the Pearson R come from in this plot?